# Apache Cassandra Data Storage on Disk

Tags: cassandra

Is Cassandra's data stored only in the `/var/lib/cassandra` folder as mentioned in the `cassandra.yaml` file?

Or is there any other location where Cassandra data is stored?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can change the data storage location in the `cassandra.yaml` file, if you don't want data stored in `/var/lib`. See [DataStax's Guide for Configuring Cassandra](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/configuration/node_configuration) for a full explanation of the config file. In particular,

> **> commitlog_directory**
>
> > The directory where the commit log will be
> >     stored. For optimal write performance, DataStax recommends the commit
> >     log be on a separate disk partition (ideally a separate physical
> >     device) from the data file directories.
> >
> > **> data_file_directories**
> >     The directory location where column family data
> >     (SSTables) will be stored.

They do recommend you put the commit log one disk and the actual data on a second disk to avoid running out of space.

Comment: You may also want to specify a new path for saved_caches_directory, which is also in /var/lib by default.

Answer (score -2):

The full list of properties are below.

hints_directory:

data_file_directories:

commitlog_directory:

saved_caches_directory: